# RollupJS + Uglify: Incorrect Sourcemap

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, rollupjs

We're using grunt to run RollupJS to generate an iife.
This works fine on its own - all the sourcemaps work, and I can debug in Chrome without issue.

However, we were then trying to run the file through UglifyJS (via the grunt task), to concatenate a few other flat files, and uglify the result.
I'm passing the existing sourcemap file through via the sourceMapIn property in Uglify.   This outputs a normal-looking sourcemap, but in Chrome all of the line-number mappings are incorrect.  We're not able to debug anywhere.

Has anyone else successfully used a RollupJS + Uglify, with a working sourcemap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [rollup-plugin-uglify](https://github.com/TrySound/rollup-plugin-uglify). That way, Rollup can combine the sourcemap from Uglify with previous steps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I attempted to use the uglify rollup plugin, but we're getting the same result as the stand-alone uglify grunt task.  However, when we go to debug in-browser, I'm still getting incorrect line number mappings.  I can't break on specific lines - the breakpoint will bounce around to other lines.  I've removed all the other variables I can think of - its just a simple rollup -> uglify.   My only suspect is that we're using the uglify-es branch to handle ES6 syntax.

Comment: I've also just attempted to add Babel to the mix, to transpile to ES5, so we could use the regular Uglify branch.   Same result.   Breakpoint on line 108 pops down to line 123..

Comment: Hmm. Impossible to diagnose without a [repro](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/88c5fc2ac6dc941b22e7996af05d70ff) I'm afraid!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Rollup-plugin-terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-terser), works fine for me.
Alternatively, please provide details of rollup config and code example for further debugging.